# PageViewer: How to get class of adjacent pages?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I use a PageViewer to scroll through two types of fragments.
One of them has an EditText the other multiple buttons.
Upon entering the EditText Fragment I automatically open the softkeyboard. Upon entering the Button Fragment i close it.
This works fine. 
The problem is that I have multiple EditText Fragments as direct neighbours to each other. 
-> I dont want the keyboard to be closed when transitioning from one EditText Fragment to the next. 
For this I somehow need to predict the class to which I am transitioning next.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Note: I close the keyboard in the pageTransform method as soon as a swipe movement occurs.

EDIT
because of an request in the comments here my PagerAdapter:

```
public class ButtonCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ButtonCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    private Fragment currentFragment;

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        List<MultipleChoiceQuestion> multipleChoiceQuestions = QuestionTexts.getMCQuestionTexts();
        List<String> questionTexts = QuestionTexts.getQuestionTexts();

       if(i < multipleChoiceQuestions.size()){
           String question = multipleChoiceQuestions.get(i).getText();
           ArrayList<String> choices = (ArrayList<String>) multipleChoiceQuestions.get(i).getChoices();
           currentFragment = ButtonFragment.newInstance(question, choices, i);
       } else if(i < (multipleChoiceQuestions.size() + questionTexts.size())){
            currentFragment = TextViewFragment.newInstance(questionTexts.get(i - multipleChoiceQuestions.size()), i);
       } else {
            currentFragment = SendFragment.newInstance(i);
       }
       return currentFragment;
    }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
      return 23;
   }

   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
   }

   @Override
   public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
       super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
       currentFragment = (Fragment) object;
       ((PagerAdapterUpdateProgress) object).onGettingPrimary(position);
   }

   public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
      return currentFragment;
   }
```

}

Comment: So, you close the keyboard before settling in the next page. right?   The user can swipe and then return back without settling at the next page what would you do in this situation?

Comment: 1.: That is correct.
2.: If i cannot find an easy way to reopen it I would let the user click on the EditText to open the keyboard again.

Comment: I think there is another option. I'll explain it in an answer.

Comment: Can you post your PagerAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

I think the more simple way to do that is to open/close keyboard directly from your fragments. You can determine when your fragment becomes visible by overriding `setUserVisibleHint` method of your fragment. The code in this method for your EditText Fragment should just show keyboard, and the code for other fragment should hide keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.

I believe that you can achieve what you are doing by using [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) listener especially [onPageSelected(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected(int)) method in which we could get the position of the currently selected fragment after the swipe animation has finished.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       Log.d("ViewPager", "Page selected " + position);
       onPageSelectedLogic(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
// This is because the first fragment doesn't fire the OnPageChangeListener.
onPageSelectedLogic(0);
```

an this is the implementation of `onPageSelectedLogic` method

```
private void onPageSelectedLogic(int position) {
   // Check the type of the fragment editable vs button
   if(!mPagerAdpater.isFragmentEdiatable(position)) {
      // Close the Keyboard
   }
}
```

And this is how you should implement your `PagerAdapter`

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private SparseBooleanArray fragmentsEditable = new SparseBooleanArray();

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fargment;
            // get the fragment
            if(some condition) {
               // Get an editable fragment
               fragmentsEditable.put(position, true);
            } else {
               fragmentsEditable.put(position, false);
            }

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

        public boolean isFragmentEditable(int postion) {
            return fragmentsEditable.get(postion);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know `onPageSelected` is not invoked for the first fragment. So if the first is EditText Fragment then you will have no chance to show keyboard.

Comment: Nice catch. We can overcome that. I'll edit my answer.